# Telethon MessageMediaDocument MD5

Tags: telegram, telethon

I'm working on a Telegram client using [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) library. I fetch recent messages from a channel and filter messages containing an APK file. Here is some part of the python code:

```py
import time
import config
import database
from datetime import datetime
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync
from telethon.tl.types import Channel, MessageMediaDocument
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetHistoryRequest


def extract_channels(dialogs):
    result = []
    if dialogs:
        for dialog in dialogs:
            entity = dialog.entity
            if isinstance(entity, Channel):
             result.append(entity)
    return result

client = TelegramClient('some_name', config.api_id, config.api_hash)
me = client.start(
                 phone=config.phone_number, 
                 password=config.two_factor_auth_password
                 )
open_dialogs = me.get_dialogs()
channels = extract_channels(open_dialogs)

database.connect()

for channel in channels:
    last_message_id = database.get_last_message_id(channel.id)
    channel_messages = client(GetHistoryRequest(
        peer=channel,
        offset_id=0,
        offset_date=None,
        add_offset=0,
        limit=0 if last_message_id else config.limit,
        max_id=0,
        min_id=last_message_id,
        hash=0)
    )
    messages = channel_messages.messages
    if messages:
        for message in messages[::-1]:
            media = message.media
            if isinstance(media, MessageMediaDocument):
                if media.document.mime_type.lower() == config.apk_mime_type:
                    // apk_md5 = media.md5 ???
                    check_apk_md5_in_db(apk_md5)    
        time.sleep(config.wait_seconds)

database.close()
```

Then i need to get MD5 of the APK but i have to download the APK file first, which is costly for my current environment because there a lot of APK files i have to fetch. So is there any way to obtain MD5 of the file in a message without downloading it? I've searched around the Telethon and Telegram documentation but i couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: Why do you need MD5? Please explain more

Comment: @Alihosseinshahabi I have a database with a lot of md5 s, I need to obtain md5 of the apk to see whether it is inside the database, if so download the apk otherwise ignore it.

Comment: Each media (including photos, videos, files, ...) has a unique `Media_id` in Telegram.
I suggest you save `Media_id` instead of `MD5`.

Comment: @Alihosseinshahabi yes, they have a unique id but i my case, i've been given a database of md5 to look for inside some channels. Anyway thanks for your comment.